# Запрос MySQL с 3 и более вариантами OR

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, pdo

Помогите, делаю поиск по БД, но не могу понять как правильно сформировать запрос. 
Есть таблица, в которой 10 столбцов, Я хочу что бы через форму поиска, можно было найти строки, по заданным параметрам столбцов, для этого использую конструкцию 'OR', но если первое значение unknow, а в 3 добавить данные - то поиск возвращается пустой:

```sql
SELECT * FROM default_fpl WHERE `departure` LIKE '' 
                            OR `arrival` LIKE ''
                            OR `route`  LIKE 'MARSHUT'
                            OR `commentaries` LIKE '' 
                            OR `FPL_name` LIKE '' LIMIT 50
```

Данный запрос вернет 0 резльтатов, но стоит изменить чуть-чуть:

```sql
SELECT * FROM default_fpl WHERE `departure` LIKE 'UUUU' 
                            OR `arrival` LIKE ''
                            OR `route`  LIKE 'MARSHUT'
                            OR `commentaries` LIKE '' 
                            OR `FPL_name` LIKE '' LIMIT 50
```

Тогда возвращается только значение по первому совпадению, т.е. UUUU

Как правильно сформировать запрос, что бы поиск происходил по разным столбцам?

В PDO запрос выглядит так:

```php
         $fplfindSql = "SELECT * FROM default_fpl WHERE departure LIKE :departure 
                        OR arrival LIKE :arrival
                        OR route LIKE :route 
                        OR commentaries LIKE :comment 
                        OR FPL_name LIKE :fplname LIMIT 50";

         $params = [':departure' => $departure,
                    ':arrival'=>$arrival,
                    ':route'=>$route,
                    ':comment'=>$comment,
                    ':fplname'=>$fplname];

         $stmt = $pdo->prepare($fplfindSql);
         $stmt->execute($params);
```

Или сделать отдельный запрос для каждой переменной? Но тогда нагрузка на базу будет расти?

Comment: Скобочки расставлять не пробовали? А вставлять целиком условие проверки, а не только литерал? А вставлять правильный шаблон? должно помогать - и то, и это...

Comment: Да, если заполнять в запросе все данные - то и ответ нормальный. Проблема возникает если первых двух данных нет. Скобочки пробовал, но не совсем понимаю в каких местах их правильно расставить)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Генерируйте запрос динамически

```php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM default_fpl ";
    $where = '';
    foreach ($data as $key => $val){
        if (!empty($val)){
           if (!empty($where))
              $where .= ' AND ';
           $where .= " `{$key}` LIKE '%{$val}%' ";
        }
    }
    if (!empty($where))
      $sql .= ' WHERE '. $where;
    $sql .= ' LIMIT 50';
```

Чтото на подобии такого.. условия легко можна регулировать для пдо цикл можно изменить на пример ниже, но не уверен как тут генерит like.

```php
      foreach ($params as $key => $val){
        if (!empty($val)){
           if (!empty($where))
              $where .= ' AND ';
              $fieldName = ltrim($key, ':');
           $where .= "`{$fieldName}` LIKE {$key}";
        }
```

Comment: Хороший вариант, спасибо! Но данный метод предполагает несколько запросов в базу?

Comment: @DraCk901, нет, запрос в бд будет 1. Данный код просто строит конечный вариант запроса в бд

Answer (score 0):

Убери Like и замени на равно:

Если нужно чтобы все условия выполнились:

```
SELECT * FROM `moder` WHERE `pred` = '0' AND `kik` = '0' AND `tban` = '0' AND `ban` = '0' AND `mut` = '0'
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если нужно чтобы только одно из них:

```
SELECT * FROM `moder` WHERE `pred` = '0' OR `kik` = '0' OR `tban` = '0' OR `ban` = '0' OR `mut` = '0'
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: К сожалению, мне нужно что бы было именно LIKE т.к. возможно не полное соответствие в запросе от пользователя

Answer (score 0):

Измените шаблон основы запроса, сделайте его таким:

```
SELECT * FROM default_fpl WHERE 1=1
```

И затем добавляйте условия только для тех полей, которые заданы, в форме

```
OR `route` LIKE 'MARSHUT'
```

Когда закончите, навесьте на хвост требуемое

```
LIMIT 50
```

В итоге получите запрос без проверок на пустые поля.

---

LIKE с шаблоном, который не содержит подстановочных знаков, представляет из себя фактически проверку на равенство - только с дополнительными, нафиг не нужными, операциями.

Если Вы проверяете полное значение поля - вместо показанного выше добавляемого условия должно быть

```
OR `route` = 'MARSHUT'
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, Я забыл указать %value%  в коде в данном вопросе. Мне нравится Ваш вариант, возможно будет эффективнее сделать проверку какого нибудь значения на подобие "id != 0" что бы он проверял доступны ли вообще строки. И дальше пошёл проверять по заданным параметрам в 'OR'